# DELETE FROM SELF JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete duplicate records with older dates.  I just uploaded some dups with a later date and only want to keep those.

The following is my code

```
DELETE FROM 
    Config 
WHERE
(
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Config one
INNER JOIN 
    Config two
ON 
    one.name = two.name 
    and 
    one.product = two.product
WHERE 
    (one.name LIKE '4%' OR one.Name LIKE '7%' OR one.Name LIKE '9%') 
    AND 
    (one.date < two.date)
)
```

I'm having the darndest time getting this one.

**EDIT : ADD Table schema**

```
ConfigID GUID UNIQUE IDENTIFIER
name     varchar(100),
Product  varchar(50),
Amount   smallint,
Date     datetime
```

Comment: Could you post the table schema?

Comment: @wewesthemenace will be up in a min

Comment: You want to delete duplicate entries for Product and name and leave the one with the latest date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
delete one
FROM 
    Config one
    INNER JOIN 
        Config two
    ON 
        one.name = two.name 
        and one.product = two.product
    WHERE 
        (one.name LIKE '4%' OR one.Name LIKE '7%' OR one.Name LIKE '9%') 
        AND (one.date < two.date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        *, Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product, Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
    FROM Config
    WHERE
        name  LIKE '4%'
        OR name  LIKE '7%'
        OR name  LIKE '9%'
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE Rn > 1
```

Comment: I've haven't used ranking queries yet so chose the other answer.  I upvoted because it looks right and I know I can do it this way....Is this script basically ranking by date?

Comment: Yup, basically it groups first by product and name and rank them according to date.

Comment: Excellent...I need to start using these.   Is this a more optimal strategy?

Comment: I believe so. This is the more known way to delete duplicates. You can read it over here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx